# Tweetinvi not uploading video greater than 15MB

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

Im using Tweetinvi and can upload files < 15MB without problem. however over that it fails, even though the Twitter API official docs state "File size should not exceed 15 mb (sync) / 512 mb (async)". I had assumed Tweetinvi would be using async logic and therefore should work, but seems not.

Any ideas if Im doing anything wrong or simply if Tweetinvi doesnt allow this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is my bad. Im really sorry but it appears someone had revoked my API permissions without telling me, but for some reason I wasnt getting the relevant error when I called the upload. It was only when i tried to do a simple Tweetinvi.Account.GetCurrentAccountSettings that i got the relevant error that helped me track it down.

Comment: Could you please provide more information regarding the media_category you are using? Also, could you please let me know if I can close the twittercommunity ticket? If this question is closed please mark it as resolved ;)

Comment: It is resolved. Your code works fine. It was related to someone remove my app's credentials in twitter...

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of Tweetinvi.

When the upload was implemented, the async was not part of the REST API.
But as I can read, this seems to be dependent on the `media_category`.

Please try to set the `media_category` to `amplify_video` as followed.

```
var binary = File.ReadAllBytes("filepath");
var media = Upload.UploadVideo(binary, mediaCategory: "amplify_video");
```

Then use the `Upload.GetMediaStatus` to know when the upload has successfully completed.

```
var status = Upload.GetMediaStatus(media);

if (status.ProcessingInfo.State == "succeeded")
{
    // You can now publish your tweet
}
```

Documentation : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Upload#upload-status-video

Please note that Upload will be slightly improved in the next release of Tweetinvi (1.2).

Regardless of whether this solution works or not please let me know so that I can investigate and fix any potential bug or update the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Hi there. Firstly many thanks for building this very useful project.

Comment: But unfortunately, i already had that setting applied so it does not appear to work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will make a request on the Twitter website.

Comment: Have you tried with `tweet_video` as media category?

Comment: You can find the post on twitter website here : https://twittercommunity.com/t/upload-limit-for-video-async/76029